# Facebook Logout / CakePHP Plugin

Tags: cakephp, facebook-graph-api, facebook

In in the CakePHP SDK for Facebook, the following code is provided for logging out:

```
<?php echo $this->Facebook->logout(array('redirect'=>array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'))); ?>
```

This codes doesn't seem to work, as the API seems to have changed to now use "next" as opposed to redirect. So the above code doesn't produce a logout button; just a link;

The following code produces a logout button, but doesn't actually redirect:

```
<?php echo $this->Facebook->logout(array('next'=>array('controller'=>'users','action'=>'logout'))); ?>
```

Any idea what needs to be done to address this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$params = array( 'next' => 'https://www.myapp.com/after_logout' );

$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params); // $params is optional.
```

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/